# Paypal Sandbox Invoice API Internal Error for rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

For rails application for paypal create invoice api getting internal error.

Following is code which I am running on my rails console.

```
    items = {:name=> 'Deposit Invoice', :unitPrice=>11, :quantity=>1}

    i = create('paypal_persoanl_account_email',items,'merchant_email')

    def create(payer_email, items, merchant_email)
    invoice = api.build_create_and_send_invoice({
       :invoice => {
         :merchantEmail => merchant_email,
         :payerEmail => payer_email,
         :itemList => {
           :item => items
         },
         :currencyCode => "USD",
         :paymentTerms => "NoDueDate" } })
    api.create_and_send_invoice(invoice)
  end
```

Response:

```
 <PayPal::SDK::Invoice::DataTypes::CreateAndSendInvoiceResponse:0x00000006ef05c8 @responseEnvelope=#<PayPal::SDK::Invoice::DataTypes::ResponseEnvelope:0x00000006ef0500 @timestamp=Tue, 24 Mar 2015 03:17:31 -0700, @ack="Failure", @correlationId="f2b8ed569338c", @build="15658184">, @error=[#<PayPal::SDK::Invoice::DataTypes::ErrorData:0x00000006eef790 @errorId=520002, @domain="PLATFORM", @subdomain="Application", @severity="Error", @category="Application", @message="Internal Error">]>
```

Comment: I think Paypal are currently experiencing an outage, even their status pages are currently down.

Comment: @SteveEdson, you are correct there is some paypal sandbox issue. Now it is working fine.